# What front-end and back-end technologies do Google and Facebook use?

Tags: c++, python, facebook

What technologies do Google and Facebook use for their back-end and front-end?

What are their database technologies, and languages they use to process the back-end data.

Comment: somebody should add the tags c++ and python

Comment: @Dienekes which one? I'm not talking about SO

Comment: When you asked Google and Facebook, what did they say?  WHy ask us?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

http://web.archive.org/web/20110708015633/http://panela.blog-city.com/python_at_google_greg_stein__sdforum.htm

> - Where is Python used?
>
>   - The Google build system is written in python.  All of Google's
>       corporate code is checked into a
>       repository and the dependency and
>       building of this code is managed by
>       python.  Greg mentioned that to create
>       code.google.com took about 100 lines
>       of python code.  But since it has so
>       many dependencies, the build system
>       generated a 3 megabyte makefile for
>       it!
>   - Packaging.  Google has an internal packaging format like RPM. 
>       These packages are created using
>       python.
>   - Binary Data Pusher.  This is the area where Alex Martelli is working,
>       on optimizing pushing bits between
>       thousands of servers
>   - Production servers.  All monitoring, restarting and data
>       collection functionality is done with
>       python
>   - Reporting.  Logs are analyzed and reports are generated using
>       Python.
>   - A few services including code.google.com and google groups. 
>       Most other front ends are in C++
>       (google.com) and Java (gmail).  All
>       web services are built on top of a
>       highly optimizing http server wrapped
>       with SWIG.

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20110708015633/http://panela.blog-city.com/python_at_google_greg_stein__sdforum.htm

Answer (score 2):

I can tell you that Facebook uses PHP as a frontend presentation layer and backend is mostly MySQL and (for message search) Cassandra. More information can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/marcialwushu/6b5928f5f3f7f97a06139677513e6a2d).

Google uses BigTable for backend repository (I don't know if they use MySQL or other technologies).

Answer (score 1):

Google makes use of [Map Reduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) to process huge amount of data.[Facebook](http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=16121578919) uses an open source implementation of Map Reduce called [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Heard a rumor that Facebook uses Erlang for its messaging system:
http://gregosuri.com/how-facebook-uses-erlang-for-real-time-chat

Answer (score 1):

Facebook uses HBase for its messaging infrastructure. Have attached the paper published by Facebook on how they used HBase and the optimizations they have done. Its a good read: http://sites.computer.org/debull/A12june/facebook.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Google tree whales: [Google File System](http://labs.google.com/papers/gfs.html), [BigTable](http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable.html) and [MapReduce](http://labs.google.com/papers/mapreduce.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking about both front-end and back-end, you maybe interested in the part inbetween: How they communicate between different systems.

For this Google and Facebook use [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/) and [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) respectively.